# How can I restore my raspberry pi sources list

Tags: raspbian, linux, raspberry-pi-os, source.list

I changed something which bricked my rpi. I changed `sources.list` and `raspi.list` then when I run `sudo apt update` I am getting this error:

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

How can I restore `sources.list` and `raspi.list`?

Comment: And I am using Raspberry Pi 3b+ Buster

Comment: More important than the hardware you're running is: which version of the OS you're using?... e.g. `buster`?? `stretch` is a possibility, but quite **old** now.

Answer (score 8):

These are the default entries from an unmodified image:

```
    rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
    deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
    # Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
    #deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi

    rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
    deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main
    # Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
    #deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main
```

After you restore these values, you will need to run `sudo apt update` again.